# Can I combine git-archive with git-grep?

Tags: git, git-archive, git-grep

For a DevOps solution I'm looking for a way to combine git archive with git grep. Is it possible to combine this? e.g.:

```
 git archive --remote=url.project.git HEAD: git grep -i searchString $(git branch -r) | tar -x
```

Comment: Can you explain what that command would accomplish?

Comment: To amplify what @LasseV.Karlsen said: presumably, you tried your example and it does not work (I know it won't do anything useful), but you haven't said what you'd *like to get as a result*. My guess—which is just a guess—is that you want to find files in `HEAD` that contain some specific string, and then turn those files into an archive.

Comment: Yes, the result should be a subset of scripts in HEAD which are dynamicly archived.

Comment: Which subset?  In particular, if I ran `git clone` and then `git grep -i searchString $(git branch -r)`, are those all the files that should go into this archive? Remember that this is *more than one commit* and many of these files will have the *same path name*, and therefore cannot all go into one archive.

Comment: Subset like, only files with a header note #oracle database for example.